# Merge two arrays based upon there position to create a new array using lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have two arrays of objects and i would like to merge it based on there position. Below is the example and expected result:

```
let patientLocation = [
    [{
        "value": "CARDIOLOGY B1 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "label": "Team: CARDIOLOGY B1 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "filterType": "team"
    }],
    [{
        "value": "CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "label": "Team: CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "filterType": "team"
    }]
];


let patientsNames = [
    [{
        "value": "LAST_CARD, FIRST_CARD",
        "label": "LAST_CARD, FIRST_CARD (12345677)",
        "filterType": "name"
    }],
    [{
        "value": "REACT_CARD, FIRST_CARD",
        "label": "REACT_CARD, FIRST_CARD (12345678)",
        "filterType": "name"
    }]
];
```

Expected Result:

```
result = [
    [{
        "value": "LAST_CARD, FIRST_CARD",
        "label": "LAST_CARD, FIRST_CARD (12345677)",
        "filterType": "name"
    }, {
        "value": "CARDIOLOGY B1 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "label": "Team: CARDIOLOGY B1 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "filterType": "team"
    }],
    [{
        "value": "REACT_CARD, FIRST_CARD",
        "label": "REACT_CARD, FIRST_CARD (12345678)",
        "filterType": "name"
    }, {
        "value": "CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "label": "Team: CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "filterType": "team"
    }]
];
```

I have tried this using map but not getting desired result.

```
result = patientLocation.map(function (e, i) {
            return [e, patientsNames[i]];
          });
```

Comment: So what you want is `[A, B] + [C, D] => [[A, C], [B, D]]`?

Comment: yes. you got that right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need lodash for a problem as simple as this one. Use `map` with the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this:

```js
let patientLocation = [
    [{
        "value": "CARDIOLOGY B1 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "label": "Team: CARDIOLOGY B1 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "filterType": "team"
    }],
    [{
        "value": "CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "label": "Team: CARDIOLOGY B2 INTERN1 ADMIT PRIMARY TEAM",
        "filterType": "team"
    }]
];


let patientsNames = [
    [{
        "value": "LAST_CARD, FIRST_CARD",
        "label": "LAST_CARD, FIRST_CARD (12345677)",
        "filterType": "name"
    }],
    [{
        "value": "REACT_CARD, FIRST_CARD",
        "label": "REACT_CARD, FIRST_CARD (12345678)",
        "filterType": "name"
    }]
];

let arr = patientsNames.map((obj, i) => [...obj, ...patientLocation[i]])

console.log(arr)
```